# facebook-c#-sdk

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have the following requirement now and I would like to know whether this is possible or not.

a) I have a VC++ application and I would like to upload some photos to a facebook account through this application.

b) The main issue here is that, I have the user id, password, app Id, secret key etc. with my application and I would like to login to the facebook account programatically (basically it should not ask for the login information again by displaying the facebook login window)

c) Is it possible to do the above requirement? That is, I need to pass the stored login credentials to the facebook server and get the access to my account.

Any help in this regard will be really appreciated.

Comment: you ask for VC++ but tag C#. What language are you going to use?

Comment: You cant login automaticlly (this is not allowed by the facebook policy). What you can do, is give your application the offline_access permission. Then you dont NEED to log in.

Comment: Right now it is VC++. But I can shift to C# also.... main requirement is to login using stored parameters.

Comment: See the detailed workflow:            1) User opens and application. 2) It has a credential settings window and he has entered the user id and password (other required details also, if required) 3) then he tries to upload some pictures to face book. 4) Then the application has to use the credentials and access the specified account and update the photos.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi,Here do you means that there is no mechanism available as of now to connect to facebook account programatically (by using my saved credential information)?

Comment: Not that I know of anyway. The user needs to login through the facebook login dialog and only then can you get an oauth token for them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) is meant for .net framework. So unless you are running in managed C++, it wouldnt be much of help.

As for authentication you will need to use OAuth. The documentation can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

I would also suggest you to read this article if you can shift to C# as you mentioned. http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx

For photo uploading you might want to refer to this answer [Post to wall fail when a picture is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260273/post-to-wall-fail-when-a-picture-is-added)

Comment: Here do you means that there is no mechanism available as of now to connect to facebook account programatically (by using my saved credential information)?

Comment: you are not supposed to use username and password to login. you have to use the access_token or oauth_token. i strongly recommend you to read the authentication documentation first.

Comment: Ok. I have already gone through the documentation and for the Dektop application i could see that the information with title "Desktop Apps". There also it is mentioned that : "Embed a web browser and load the OAuth Dialog". Here my understanding is that the only way to get an access is via a manual entry of login id and password to authorize the application. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to login to facebook using a vc++ connector, means the user cant provide his/her credentials to the connector to perform the login/authentication without using the browser.